# How to change axis labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following piece of code which creates a simple plot with matplotlib (python 3.6.9, matplotlib 3.1.2, Mac Mojave):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)))
plt.show()
```

The created plot is as expected:

[image]

Now, in order to relabel the xtick/ytick labels I am using the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)));

ticks, labels = plt.xticks()
labels[1] = '22'
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)

plt.show()
```

where I expect the second label to be replaced by '22', but everything else stays the same. However, I get the following plot instead:

[image]

1. There is some unexpected white area in the left part of the plot
2. All the other labels have vanished.

How to do it correctly?

Just as a reminder: I want to get the exact same result as the original image (first plot), ONLY with one of the lables changed.

This question has been asked before, one example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918971/modify-a-specific-x-axis-tick-label-in-python). But the answer does not seem to work. Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)))

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels[1] = 'Test'
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

which creates an image as follows:

[image]

which does not show the white area anymore, but still the other labels are not shown.

Answer (score 3):

Create axes using subplots, so that you can have set_xticklabels method, so you can update the labels.

You need to use, canvas.draw() to get the values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)));
fig.canvas.draw()
#labels = ['-10','0','22','20','30','40'] or
labels[2]=22
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output image]

Hope this is what you need!

Comment: No, you did not understand what I want. I want the original plot, and instead where the number '10' is written on the x-axis, I want that number '10' replaced - at the exact same location, with something else. Just something else.

Comment: Got it! I'll update my answer soon!

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but in that case I have to 'guess' the other labels? Can't that be done automatically? Why do I have to redefine the existing labels? It works fine for the example,. but when I use a different plot, scale etc that does not work. Do I have to 'try' all the time then?

Comment: Check the edit, you can do it by using canvas.draw() to retrieve the existing labels. if you don't use it, then all zeros are shown.